# Show available/installed version in the output of aptitude search

Tags: aptitude

Is it possible to make `aptitude` show the available/installed version of a package in an output of `aptitude search mypackage`?

I know that I can show the version via `aptitude show mypackage`, but I want it it to appear also in the output of an `aptitude` search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you. Put this in a script file named `apt-version.sh` and make it executable.

```
#!/bin/bash
TERMS=$@
for name in $(apt-cache search "$TERMS" | sed 's/ .*//'); do
    echo "$name "
    apt-cache show $name | grep -i -e "description-en" -e "version" | sed 's/^/    /'
done
```

A test. Put your search terms after the name when you run it.

```
$ ./apt-version.sh  mesa-util
mesa-utils 
    Version: 8.0.1+git20110129+d8f7d6b-0ubuntu2
    Description-en: Miscellaneous Mesa GL utilities
mesa-utils-extra 
    Version: 8.0.1+git20110129+d8f7d6b-0ubuntu2
    Description-en: Miscellaneous Mesa utilies (opengles, egl)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not yet exactly what I want: I want just add the version to the usual `aptitude search` output (where also a very short description of the package is included)

Comment: I edited it so that it prints out the package description too.